# How can I use Python to implement Object functions like ObjectCreate(), ObjectDelete(), ObjectMove from MetaTrader library?

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, metatrader4, metatrader5

I am converting MQ4-based Trading Bot into Python-based Trading Bot for several days. I could use MetaTrader library in Python and Pytrader on Github for this solution.
But I couldn't implement Object functions like ObjectCreate(), ObjectDelete(), ObjectMove and so on by Python MetaTrader.

How can I implement those object functions in Python?

Thanks.

I tried to use MetaTrader, Pytrader for solving this problem. And I asked ChatGPT-4 as well.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.